# XML Parsing Error: syntax error in Spark framework

Tags: java, spark-java

java:

```
package com.test;

import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Spark.get(new Route("/") {
            @Override
            public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
                return "Hello from Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Running this code giving the following error at **localhost:4567**:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://localhost:4567/
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Hello from Spark
^
```

Example is taken from http://youtu.be/UH-VD_ypal8

Comment: Smells like a problem with the client and expected response type. What do you get with `curl http://localhost:4567/`?

Comment: Showing: Hello from Spark

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `response.type("text/plain");` or change your response value to valid XML for viewing in this client.

Comment: where should I put this line?

Comment: Before the return statement. That's where `response` is in scope. Be sure its value is 'text/plain'. I wrote the wrong thing initially in this answer.

Comment: Here are some other things you can do with the response object: http://www.sparkjava.com/readme.html#title4

Comment: I changed this way: public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response) {
                response.type("text/plain");
                return "Hello from Spark"; but the error remains
            }

Comment: If you see, example at http://www.sparkjava.com/readme.html#title0 not using response.type(), and it's giving the same error

Comment: I did the same course and that code in the video works. What client (browser) are you using?

Comment: Thanks for hint. I noticed this is happening with Firefox. For Chrome it's ok.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this yet? I tried this with plain text, as well as messing around with other headers, and it seems to still be breaking, even though all my headers are identical to another web framework that works with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the response type to 'text/xml'. please let us know what happens

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error under firefox (while curl showed expected answer). just added response type

```
        public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            response.type("text/plain");
            return "spark";
        }
```

and browser showed right answer